# how to improve performance of writing data to MongoDB using Spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I use python Spark to run a heavy iterative computing job and write data to MongoDB. In each iteration, there may contain 0.01 ~ 1 billion data in RDD or DataFrame to be computed(this procedure is simple and relatively fast) and about 100,000 data to be written to MongoDb. The problem is that procedure seems get stuck in MongoSpark Job every iteration(see image below). I don't know what is going on in this job. The computing part seems already have finished(see Job "runJob at PythonRDD.scala"). MongoDB, however, doesn't receive any data in most time of this job. In my estimation, writing 100,000 data to MongoDB directly only cost tiny time.

**Can you explain what costs most time of this job, and how to improve the performance of this ?**

Thanks for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to be mapping partitions from MongoDB. If you are just saving data then it shouldn't need to do that. However, without seeing any code it will be hard to diagnose the real cause.

Comment: Also it looks like each `foreachPartition` is taking longer and longer. Is there a logical reason for that? Again without seeing any code its hard to understand the cause.

Comment: I am also having same issue, this is the piece of code I used: 

    datasource0.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").option("uri", "mongodb://"+DBHost+"/DB.COLLECTION").mode("append").save()

Is there anything I need to change to speedup writing?